# Query start and stop dates between two date fields

Tags: sql, date, between

I have a start order date field and a stop order field I need to check the database to see if the start and stop orders are outside of any of the pay period start and end fields. Say 01-aug-10 and 14-aug-10 and 15-aug-10 and 28-aug-10 and 29-aug-10 and 11-sep-10 are all of the pay periods in one month. The start order 01-aug-10 and the end order is 14-aug-10. Yet when I do a SQL that said (where end order not between pay period start and pay period end) the 01-aug-10 to 14-aug-10 still shows up. My needs are if it finds any dates that match stop looking and go to the next record start order and stop order and start the next search till we hit the end of the record search requirements.

I am looking to search by month and by year to keep the query responsive. The database is quite large. My query seams like it only does the between check once and then it shows all of the data that does fit between the pay period start and stop, and that is the data I do not want to see!

Answer (score 1):

What dbms?

So you have a table like this?

```
CREATE TABLE something
(
  pay_period_start date NOT NULL,
  pay_period_end date NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT something_pkey PRIMARY KEY (pay_period_start),
  CONSTRAINT something_pay_period_end_key UNIQUE (pay_period_end),
  CONSTRAINT something_check CHECK (pay_period_end > pay_period_start)
);
insert into something values ('2010-08-01', '2010-08-14');
insert into something values ('2010-08-15', '2010-08-28');
insert into something values ('2010-08-29', '2010-09-11');
```

Then I can run this query. ('2010-08-14' is the value of your stop order column or end order column or something like that.)

```
select * from something
where '2010-08-14' not between pay_period_start and pay_period_end
order by pay_period_start;
```

and I get

```
2010-08-15;2010-08-28
2010-08-29;2010-09-11
```

For pairs of dates, use the OVERLAPS operator. This query

```
select * from something
where 
  (date '2010-08-01', date '2010-08-14') overlaps 
  (pay_period_start,  pay_period_end) 
order by pay_period_start;
```

returns

```
2010-08-01;2010-08-14
```

To exclude rows where start order and end order exactly match a pay period, use something like this:

```
select * from something
where (
  (date '2010-08-01', date '2010-08-14') overlaps 
  (pay_period_start, pay_period_end)               and
  (date '2010-08-01' <> pay_period_start)          and
  (date '2010-08-14' <> pay_period_end)
)
order by pay_period_start;
```

Comment: Ok let's try this again, is there a way to do a between using two dates (start_order and end_order) field between (ppd_start and ppd_end) when I use the ( where to_char(start_order, 'MM') = to_char(ppd_start) and to_char(end_order, 'MM')= to_char(ppd_end, 'MM')and start_order != ppd_start and end_order != ppd_end and start_order not between ppd_start and ppd_end and end_order not between ppd_start and ppd_end ) but it keeps showing me dates that fit between the ppd_start and ppd_end........why?

Comment: SQL's OVERLAPS operator takes two dates. I edited my answer to include examples of overlap.

Comment: Ok looks interesting but the SQL is running inside a web page. So that being said the drop down selections are tied to selected tables in the database, and the selected item populated the SQL. So I would like little more in site on how to work this SQL with out having to use physical dates in the field. DDL_1 selects the physical year to do the search and pulls from pp_yr and then the user selects the month to review from DDL_2 that pulls from ppd_mon (1 -12) then does a compare by using to_char(start_order, 'MM') = ppd_mon and to_char(end_order, 'MM')= ppd_mon and start_order not between ppd*

Comment: In your case, the OVERLAPS operator requires dates. You'll need to construct a valid date from the year and month your users choose. If that's not possible, you might want to have another crack at describing what you need to do, not how you're trying to do it.